# p5.js: Uncaught Error: [object Arguments]is not a valid color representation

Tags: p5.js

I am working on 2D arrays to create a bookshelf, and wanted to have random colors assigned to each book. I have the code working, with 14 hex colors randomly chosen at each refresh, and applied to each of the 14 books.
But I wanted to improve my code, so this error does not show up:

```
p5.min.js:7 Uncaught Error: [object Arguments]is not a valid color representation.
at d.Color._parseInputs (p5.min.js:7)
at new d.Color (p5.min.js:6)
at e.d.color (p5.min.js:6)
at d.Renderer2D.fill (p5.min.js:8)
at e.d.fill (p5.min.js:7)
at draw (sketch.js:38)
at e.redraw (p5.min.js:8)
at e.<anonymous> (p5.min.js:7)
```

```js
const colors = [];
var randomColor;
var colorCounter;
var bookCounter;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 600);
  background(200);

  colorCounter = 0;
  bookCounter = 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    colors.push("#" + randomColor);
  };

  console.log(colors);
}

function draw() {
  stroke(0, 0, 200);
  strokeWeight(5);
  noFill()
  rect(45, 45, 360, 200);
  rect(45, 250, 360, 205);

  for (var k = 0; k < 14; k++) {
    noStroke();
    fill(colors[k]);
    rect(50 + k * 20, 550, 20, 20);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
      stroke(150, 0, 0);
      console.log("Before: " + colorCounter);
      fill(colors[colorCounter]);
      colorCounter += 1;
      console.log("After: " + colorCounter);
      rect(50 + j * 50, 50 + i * 200, 50, 200);
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
      noStroke();
      textSize(20);
      fill(255);
      text("B\no\no\nk\n \n" + bookCounter, 70 + j * 50, 80 + i * 200, 100);
      bookCounter += 1;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when you pass something that is not a valid color specification (a number, string, or Color object) to the `fill()` function. This includes passing `undefined`.

The error being raised in this case the result of `colorCounter` being a global variable, which is only set to 0 in `setup()`, and the fact that by default the `draw()` function is called repeatedly. You can see from your console log output that the error occurs right after "Before: 14" is displayed. The value of `colorCounter` is therefore `14` and you the try to call `fill(colors[colorCounter])`. Since `colors` has a length of 14, the index of the last element is 13, so `colors[colorCounter]` returns undefined.

You can fix this error in one of two ways: 1) reset the values colorCounter and bookCounter in the `draw()` function, or 2) call `noLoop()` in your setup function so that the sketch is only drawn once.

Comment: Ah, right!
Thanks Paul.
Yes, reset the counter values and error gone!